Windows 10 hibernation takes 8+ minutes on occasion
My Windows 10 machine occasionally takes ages (8+ minutes) to hibernate, during which time the hard drive is in constant use.  Other times, it takes less than 1 minute.
I am aware I can use resource monitor/task manager to find out what is using the hard drive when the machine is running, but I'd like to know if I can somehow log what the machine is doing when I start hibernation, with the logging stopping when the hibernation is complete, so I can eliminate this annoying wait to turn off power.
On multiple occasions, I've also tried comparing a list of running processes before I start hibernating; when the hibernation hangs there is nothing that sticks out as begin different from when it does not hang.  Event viewer also does not contain anything useful.
Please, is there any application or other technique I can use to log in detail what the machine is doing during the hibernation process?

The reason it takes so long is that the PC is serializing all open applications and their data to HDD. Fewer open apps, and a smaller hiberfil.sys (virtual RAM) will speed hibernation.

Thanks for the comment :)  I am well aware of what hibernation does; I want to know exactly what application is causing this, and am asking for tools to identify what process is the issue.

Does it happen while in Safe Mode?

@Ramhound I'll check that, thanks for the suggestion.
